# Are spark.files fetched before JVM process starts in executors?

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

In an environment with Mesos and dockerized executors, if spark.files configuration parameter is set, are these files added to the docker before the JVM process of every executor starts?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.files` is a CLI option parsed by the Spark JVM runner, so the container is started before files are downloaded